# Define new product image attributes

Tags: magento2, product-images

For a new fashion project we want to define a new product image attribute (`color_swatch` or `pattern`). We can't use the standard color swatch functionality, because for fashion products the color swatch is mostly product specific. The definition of the new attribute(s) is exactly like in M1, and can be done in backend or in code. So far so good.

It would be nice to define image sizes via `view.xml`, so that we have a standard resize of these new images that is generated automatically. Unfortunately, the `view.xml` is validated against an XSD validation, which restricts the type options for the different images (see `vendor/magento/framework/Config/etc/view.xsd`). I tried to extend the default validation using DI, it might work (kind of) but it feels really hacky and it's absolutely neither flexible nor portable. I really thought this would be an easy task (in M1 it was very straightforward and we used it in nearly every project), but I couldn't find a solution that feels *proper*.

Has anyone already tackled a similar task? How did you solve it? I could maybe skip this `view.xml` step altogether, or rewrite the whole thing, but I feel there should be a way to get around it. Does the system have a standard way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I reported this on github. Still waiting for an answer: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5379

Answer (score 2):

Yes I agree that this XSD is too strict and we have added this as an item to be fixed in core.

In the meantime you can re-configure DI to use a custom “SchemaLocator” class where you can configure it to use an alternative XSD file which redefines original “imageType” complex type. Here is a quick example how to do that “correctly” in the given circumstances.

In DI:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Config\View">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="schemaLocator" xsi:type="object”>Your\Extension\Config\SchemaLocator</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In "Your\Extension\Config\SchemaLocator":

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver $urnResolver
 */
public function __construct(UrnResolver $urnResolver)
{
    $this->schema = $urnResolver->getRealPath('urn:magento:module:Your_Extension/etc/view.xsd');
}
```

In "Your_Extension/etc/view.xsd”:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="imageType">
            ...
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That's exactly how I tried to solve it. But with this approach I can only install my image attributes in one module, since only one DI config "wins"... It might work for project-specific modules, but it wouldn't work for 3rd party modules.

Comment: Note it should be `urn:magento:module:Your_Extension:etc/view.xsd`, thanks this works well.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've been at this for a while now trying to decipher the XSD. My extension's view.xsd is being used but I don't want to copy and change it a bit, I want to extend (or redefine) the XSD. I try to allow a new element at the same level as width/height/constrain/frame etc. but I don't think I can reference the image element since it's a local complexType? This is the first time I'm doing something with an XSD so I hope you have some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it happened, but if anyone is running into this now, the xsd validation of image types has been updated to include any string matching `<string>_<string>` and not just the builtin types. Fudging the xsd validation is no longer required, certainly as of 2.3.5 (and probably alot earlier)